# Определить несколько свойств для одного конструктора

Tags: c#

С наступающим! Помогите новичку.
В общем, у меня следующая проблема — не знаю как добавить к одному и тому же конструктору 2 и более свойств.
К примеру:

```
public void Date()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime ng = new DateTime(2017, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);
    Console.WriteLine(ng.Subtract(now));
}
```

Я сделал 2 конструктора - `Now` и `ng`
`Now` - локальное время на данный момент на машине.
`ng` - задаем дату Нового Года.
То есть, идея программы - отсчитать время до Нового Года.
Окей, мы выводим все в 3 строке, от `ng` свойством `Subtract` мы отнимаем `now`.
Все работает, но мне нужно `"ng.Subtract(now)"` перевести в другой формат,
как бы задать ему еще одно свойство `*.ToShortTimeString;`, к примеру.
То есть то, что получилось (мы вычли из `ng Now`), нам нужно добавить
еще одно свойство (перевести в короткую форму, для примера, или сделать еще какие-то операции).
Я это вижу так - мы добавляем переменную, которая будет хранить `"ng.Subtract(now);"`, к примеру `"a = Subtract(now);"` и только потом
мы выведем `"a.ToShortTimeString";`
Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Надеюсь только я не понимаю ваш эльфийский

Comment: Вы можете сколько угодно и чего угодно писать. Проблема ваша заключается в том, что при использование `Subtract` вы получаете переменную типа `TimeSpan`, которая в свою очередь не содержит `ToShortTimeString`. Делайте что бы ваша переменная и дальше оставалась `DateTime`, либо используйте `.ToString(формат)`.

Comment: Не вижу в вашем вопросе ни одного конструктора

Comment: во 1 - это у вас метод с 2 переменными 
во 2 - TimeSpan будет для этого лучше https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"До Нового 2018 года осталось");

    var cd2018 = new CountDownNewYear2018();
    cd2018.PrintCountDown();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

..

```
class CountDownNewYear2018 : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DateTime _lastMoment =
            new DateTime(year: 2018, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0);

    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    //ctor
    public CountDownNewYear2018()
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan last = _lastMoment - current;

        Console.Write($"\r{last.Days:00}:{last.Hours:00}:{last.Minutes:00}:{last.Seconds:00}");
    }

    public void PrintCountDown()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```